# Laravel - React don't change after deploy (heroku)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, laravel, apache, heroku

After done changes on local code, I pushed it on github and deploy on heroku I'm seeing still same results (react render old pages). Why it does happen? I have try to make new repo and recreate heroku app, and its keeping same. Is there any way to  force clear cache on heroku?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to Reload page with

> ctrl+shift+R

Or

2. Run your project in loca with `npm run watch`thne open new cmd and pushed your code